# How to handle multiple dynamically resizing UITableViewCells in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have cells that load content from the network, then update their contents. For example, adding a view to preview-card for a link, or a preview of an image.

This means cells vary in height greatly between the initial load, and after the data has finished trickling in.

When scrolling through a UITableView of these cells, cells will pop around a lot, and sometimes get stuck in a constant update cycle where a cell at the bottom loads, finds it has no content, shrinks, and a cell at the top is scrolled back into view, pushes the bottom cell off, loads, then shrinks; and so on, causing the UI to lock up calculating all the changes.

What is a more proper way to handle multiple dynamically resizing cells in a UITableView?

Currently the UITableViewController is a delegate for the cell as follows:

```swift
protocol TweetCellDelegate {
    // ...
    func didChangeHeight(forCell: TweetCell)
    // ...
}

class TweetCell: /* delegates */ {
    var tweetDelegate: TweetCellDelegate?
    func resized() {
        self.tweetDelegate?.didChangeHeight(forCell: self)
    }
}

class TweetsTableViewController: TweetCellDelegate {
    func didChangeHeight(forCell: TweetCell) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

`TweetCell` calls `resized()` whenever new information arrives about an image, or a link. This is collected together as much as possible if data is cached, but might be called multiple times.

Comment: (a) Use a dummy image as cell's content until it finishes loading; (b) fix the height of the cell at the initial image's height and only update it after it has finished. Anyhow, your question is too broad and included no code

Comment: @CodeDifferent Sadly I don't know what is in it until I process it! It is coming from tweets, so there could be a whole bunch of links that need preview cards, or none. It does only update the height when done, but that is the problem. What kind of code would you like to see? The cells trigger `{begin|end}Updates` in the table via a delegate, I could include that?